Series.__getitem__ treating keys as positions is deprecated
I am trying to replace values in a Pandas data frame with their means and getting this warning.
Searching Google for this warning and studying answers to similar questions doesn't clarify the situation.
Code
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"L1_x": [0, 1, 2], 
                   "L1_y": [5, 6, 7], 
                   "other": [11, 12, 3]})
points = ["L1_x", "L1_y"]

# I'm going to replace L1_x and L2_x with mean values of these columns
df[points] = df[points].mean()



:1: FutureWarning: Series.__getitem__
treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer
keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame
behavior). To access a value by position, use ser.iloc[pos]
df[points] = df[points].mean()

Please note that I don't use integer keys.
Nevertheless, the values in the data frame are replaced.
What is happening and how should I fix the code to avoid this warning?

I don't think there is anything you need to change about your code

You can just remove the list and access each column individually:
df = pd.DataFrame({"L1_x": [0, 1, 2], 
                   "L1_y": [5, 6, 7], 
                   "other": [11, 12, 3]})


df['L1_x'] = df['L1_x'].mean()
df['L1_y'] = df['L1_y'].mean()

print(df)

Results:
    L1_x  L1_y  other
0   1.0   6.0     11
1   1.0   6.0     12
2   1.0   6.0      3


I've found that df[points].mean().to_list() also removes this warning. This is shorter. Additionally, my list of columns changes in a loop, therefore I need to use additional index (points[0], points[1])
Fortunately, its lengths is always 2

why would you do this?
